# Wpf: Self-contained installation package with all assemblies

Tags: wpf, windows, .net-core, installation, windows-installer

Guys i create an installation package with .net core 3.0. I added the output needed for install. 
Now i need my package to be self-contained like publishing self-contained .net projects (**Containing all dlls needed**).

I add my **Release** publish folder files to the package, but they wouldn't contain in installation folder.

How can i exactly achieve this?

Comment: Did you google this subject and try anything?  Like https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingATinyNETCore30EntirelySelfcontainedSingleExecutable.aspx

Comment: @Andy Publishing self-contained is OK. Don't know how to package them with in setup project!